# What is the difference between normal assignment(a = b) and passing parameters in terms of forced and unforced variables?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
  int a = 5;
  double c;

  c = a;
  printf("%f\n", c);
  hey(a);


  return 0;
}

int hey(double s)
{
  printf("%f\n", s);
}
```

Output:

```
5.000000
0.000000
```

When I write `c = a`, `double` value is automatically converted to `int` value. When I passed `a` to `hey`, I thought it will do the same thing `s = a` and be automatically converted to `double` without prototype of the function or type cast. However, this is not the case.

Why am I getting different results(`5.000000` and `0.000000`)? What is the mechanism of parameter passing and normal assignment?

Comment: Your program has undefined behaviour, because no prototype of `hey` is visible at the point where you make the call and the (promoted) argument type doesn't match the eventual parameter type.

Comment: Activate your compiler warnings (and preferably, don't run your compiler in 28-years-ago compatibility mode)

Comment: If you decide not to prototype `hey()` before you call it, you are using ancient C and are taking on the responsibility to pass the correct type to the function when you call it.  Passing the incorrect type leads to undefined behaviour.  You've just demonstrated why the discipline enforced by old C (C99 is the old standard, and it's nearly 17 years old; the current standard is C11; you're using features from C90 or pre-standard C) is such a good idea.  Don't work with one hand tied behind your back.  It's hard enough to program well without throwing away the help that the compiler can give.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you for your answer. I got the idea but I really want to know why '0.000000'.

Comment: @utgoer: that depends on the calling convention: integer and floating point arguments don't necessarily end up in the same place

Comment: @utgoer Because the first time the compiler sees your `hey()` function, you call it with an `int` argument - so `int` it is.  Then your implementation of the `hey()` function says the argument is a `double`.  Too late.  That's what function prototypes are for.

Comment: Why not?  Undefined behaviour means anything is possible and there is no sane way to reason about what you get because anything was possible and all answers are valid.  You simply can't usefully reason about why you get any given result when it arises from undefined behaviour.  In the absence of a prototype,  the compiler simply pushes a (probably) 4-byte integer onto the stack, and then the function accesses an 8-byte quantity, leading to disaster.  Who knows what the mixture of bits means?

Comment: Summary, as so often on SO: 'if you knowingly do bad stuff, expect bad results'.  Passing in an int as a double is bad stuff.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler When I passed the parameters what is happening? It is obvious that it is not simply s = a.

Comment: You could look at the assembly code and see what your compilation does, but it won't really help much.  Like I said before, anything is allowed and valid when you invoke undefined behaviour. Simply don't waste your time on it.  Make sure you don't invoke undefined behaviour.  Either define the function before you call it, or declare it with a full prototype before you call it.  Anything else is pointless.

Comment: @utgoer The exact details depend on your platform and C compiler. You'd have to look at the generated code to figure out exactly what's going on.